How to define other objective function in OR-Tools to solve an assignment problem?
The problem I want to solve is the same as this text
For example, I have 3 works and 4 tasks. The costs matrix is shown below.
costs = [
        [90, 80, 75, 70],
        [35, 85, 55, 65],
        [125, 95, 90, 95],
    ]

I need to assign  each worker with one task. But I don't need to minimiz the total cost. Instead, I want to minimiz their extreme range (means that I want to make their working hours as close as possible ).
For example, if work0->task0  work1->task1 work2->task2, then their range is 5, the smallest. This is what I want to get.
I have tried to ues the MIP solver and CP-SAT solver. But there will always be mistakes.
The code below shows how MIP solver deal this problem.
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

def main():
    # Data
    costs = [
        [90, 80, 75, 70],
        [35, 85, 55, 65],
        [125, 95, 90, 95],
    ]
    num_workers = len(costs)
    num_tasks = len(costs[0])

    # Solver
    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")

    if not solver:
        return

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] is an array of 0-1 variables, which will be 1
    # if worker i is assigned to task j.
    x = {}
    for i in range(num_workers):
        for j in range(num_tasks):
            x[i, j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, "")

    # Constraints
    # Each worker is assigned to exactly one 1 task.
    for i in range(num_workers):
        solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for j in range(num_tasks)]) == 1)

    # Each task is assigned to at most one worker.
    for j in range(num_tasks):
        solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i, j] for i in range(num_workers)]) <= 1)

    # Objective
    objective_terms = []
    for i in range(num_workers):
        for j in range(num_tasks):
            objective_terms.append(costs[i][j] * x[i, j])

    objective_cost = max(objective_terms)-min(objective_terms)
    solver.Minimize(objective_cost)

    # Solve
    print(f"Solving with {solver.SolverVersion()}")
    status = solver.Solve()

    # Print solution.
    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL or status == pywraplp.Solver.FEASIBLE:
        print(f"Total cost = {solver.Objective().Value()}\n")
        for i in range(num_workers):
            for j in range(num_tasks):
                # Test if x[i,j] is 1 (with tolerance for floating point arithmetic).
                if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0.5:
                    print(f"Worker {i} assigned to task {j}." + f" Cost: {costs[i][j]}")
    else:
        print("No solution found.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Running this, the following is thrown:
Operators "<" and ">" not supported with the linear solver

The key code is this:
objective_cost = max(objective_terms)-min(objective_terms)
    solver.Minimize(objective_cost)

I know why it's wrong. The elements' data type in the list objective_terms are not int. But I don't kown to modify it. Alos,I can't think of any other way to deal this.
Is this a problem type I can use or-tools to solve?
Many thanks for your kind and warm help.

Because MIP solvers use floating point computation with some tolerance, the notion of strict equality is ill defined.
Thus the operator < and > are forbidden. You will need to use <= and >= with the right offset.
Furthermore, min() and max() are not supported. These are python constructs that are interpreted before the solver is  called. The result is unpredictable.
I recommend using CP-SAT as it defines min and max equality natively.
Start from this assignment example.
Then add the fairness part:
either look at the epsilon minimization approach in the balance group example
or
use 2 temporary variables (min_worked and max_worked) and two constraint (add_min_equality and add_max_equality) then
minimize max_worked - min_worked

the syntax is the following: target = min(expr0, expr1, expr2) where target and expr are linear expressions (x or 3 * x or x + 2...) is implemented by
    model.add_min_equality(target, [expr0, expr1, expr2])


Thank you for your reply so much. I have tried the second method you mentioned.  I have consulted the reference . But I do not understand the function add_min_equality and add_max_equality  and their parameters target and variables. Could you please tell me more about this or write more detailed code(I hope you don't mind my presumption) . Thanks again.

a grep on code samples ?

I follow your idea . max_work =model.NewIntVar(0, 125, 'max')      min_work = model.NewIntVar(0, 125, 'min')      model.add_max_equality(max_work, objective_terms)      model.add_min_equality(min_work, objective_terms)      model.minimize(max_work-min_work) （object_terms means the same as in the code above). But the answer work0->task3 work1->task1 work2->task2 is not right. It's range is 20 instead of the right answer 5. I don't understand what went wrong. Is it that I got the two variables (max_work min_work) wrong with my definitions or I used objective_terms incorrectly ?

I know what went wrong. The add_max_equality can help me to find the max_work. But add_min_equality can't return the min_work. It always return 0. That's because 0 always exists in the ** objective_terms** . What I want to get is the smallest positive number but because the existence of 0 I always get the wrong number. I have consulted some references , but always failed. I have tried to deal all possible distribution in on_solution_callback and finally got my answer. It's a little complex.So I still want to find the way don't use the callback function.Thanks!
